# ARRAYFORMULA to sum previous row cell

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have a data sheet like this.

```
Column--    |C1|C2|C3|Total|
=========================
Row--1      | 0| 0| 0|  100| (I will have some pre calculated value for total column which is not sum of the columns in this row)

Row--2      |10|20|30|  160| (sum of previous row =100+current row (10+20+30) = 160)

Row--3      | 1| 2| 3|  166|

Row--4      | 4| 5| 6|  181|
```

Today I am using a copy paste formula for each row. However, I want an array formula for SUM column so that the formula will automatically work when I add new rows.

What I want is, SUM column will contain sum of current row A through D values and previous row SUM value.

So in a google spread sheet I'll initially have 20 rows only. Based on the transactions I'll add rows and so I want an array formula so that my formula will work even after adding new rows.

Added an example sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wlWqdFwgv90s50iP-bXXBHciyualohj610qFiSatcmQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: give a proper screenshot of your data and the expected results;

Comment: @AHC I've edited the question, is it understandable?

Comment: In example I had only 4 rows. but in my sheet, they will keep on increasing. so each time I add rows, I've to manually drag the formula or paste the formula.

Comment: why not simplye `SUM(A2:D2)+E1` ? on the condition that you move your data one row down.

Comment: the formula will work for row 2. so I want in row 3, I've to drag the formula or copy paste the formula. What if I've 2000+ rows and I can't keep dragging for those many rows. More over I'll have same scenarios for some more set of columns in the same rows. so I am looking for an array formula

Comment: I don't understand your comment re copying the formula for 2000+ rows. Dragging/pasting a formula is not particularly difficult, and once it's done it's done. Besides, if you're using an Excel Table, this copying-down will be done automatically for you.

Comment: I am using an google spreadsheet. However, even in excel , if I insert new rows at the bottom, this formula is not updating to the new rows.

Comment: suppose you have 4000 rows, this is the maximum you will reach, ok? then copy paste the formula down until the 4000th row, you do this once and there you go! each time you add rows, new data, it will automatically be updated.

Comment: This  is fine. But the sheet is complicated and I want to simplify the formule in the sheet. So I am looking for an array formula. Is there a way?

Comment: None of the suggested comments or answers worked. Is there any solution?

Comment: If i want sum only two values, in one column, and two rows... For example A2+A1 , A3+A2 .. etc etc. is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Another method for an array cumulative sum:

`=ArrayFormula(SUMIF(IF(COLUMN(A1:D1),ROW(A2:A)),"<="&ROW(A2:A),A2:D))`

Answer (score 0):

I think I would go for a solution involving two formulas:

in E1, a formula that takes care of the summing per row;

```
=ArrayFormula(mmult(filter(A1:D,len(A1:A)), transpose(column(A1:D1)^0)))
```

and then in F1: the 'cumulation' of previous rows:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUMIF(ROW(A1:A1064),"<="&ROW(A1:A1064),E1:E1064))
```

(change the range to suit)

See also: [example sheet 1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BgX9Nz5uLBXFvcrxMkzILNH3bsQEpitx95HLmZaeaso/edit?usp=sharing)

If you really need a solution in one single formula, you can try:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(A1:A1064), if(row(A1:A1064)=1, mmult(A1:D1, transpose(column(A1:D1)^0)),if(A1:A1064,mmult(transpose(if(transpose(row(A1:D1064))>=row(A1:D1064),A1:A1064+B1:B1064+C1:C1064+D1:D1064, 0)),row(A1:A1064)^0),)),))
```

See also [example sheet 2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ihsugUzxsWZ0LxaDzH2_4YgIFNY9jp9p98ZPgSdgsKU/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score -1):

Try this [example sheet](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oc3fa7h9d3fsoki/sum%20example.xlsx?dl=1)
simply put this in the first row of **E**:

```
=SUM(A2:D2)
```

and then:

```
=IF((COUNTA(A3:D3)>1),SUM(A3:D3)+E2,"")
```

and drag it down to 2000+ rows.
It is done for your in the example sheet. If you add new data in the rows, you will get what you want.

Comment: This is same as sum(a3:D3)+D2 except it is not checking for value before.

Comment: I am really looking for an array formula.

Comment: @Rams you gotta explain why you need an array, and how it should function. if you need, you can bring in your **complicated** sheet and we can have a look at it and see what can be done. You can put a set of dummy data.

Comment: I've added a link with example